# Applicability of monotone convergence theorem, dominated convergence theorem and Fatou's Lemma

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the Monotone Convergence Theorem, the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the Fatou's lemma is having **Lebesgue Integrable functions** (i.e. functions with **finite** Lebesgue Integral) a **necessary** condition, i.e. they do not apply to functions with Lebesgue integral potentially equal to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?

In positive case, do they imply that also the limiting function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, i.e. with finite Lebesgue integral?

Comment: No. The hypotheses are clearly spelled out in the statements of the theorems in any decent book. In MCT and FL they assume $f_n\ge0$ is measurable, and so no, $f_n$ integrable is not required.

Comment: Thanks. My question is due to the fact that I found statements in some books requiring $f_n$ integrable. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: In MCT and FL? What books? I don't believe it.

Comment: I think my confusion is due to the fact that when I write down $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int f_nd\mu=\int f d\mu$ I'm saying that this limit exists and hence is finite. This is not the case here, right? That limit could be infinite (hence the sequence not converging) as I do not assume that the functions are Lebesgue measurable

Comment: ??? Yes, limits are allowed to be infinite. _What_ books require integrability in MCT and FL? (You do not assume the functions are measurable? Maybe that was a typo...)

Comment: "Yes, limits are allowed to be infinite"; from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition it seems that if a function has a limit then it is convergent, which means that the limit should be finite. I'm confused. I thought that if I'm asked to show that a limit exists, meaning that I should show that a sequence converges to a finite number.  Regarding the book, I don't remember which book, but for example also the statement here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Basic_theorems_of_the_Lebesgue_integral is confusing.

Comment: Words mean different things in different contexts. In some situations a limit is finite by definition. In other situations a limit is allowed to be infinite.

Comment: ??? The statements of MCT and FL on that page say nothing at all about integrability.

Comment: The statement of MCT says "then the pointwise limit $f$ of $f_k$ is Lebesgue integrable and..."

Comment: Ok, yes it does. It shouldn't. That's an error. You can't believe everything you read on the internet. Let me know if you remember what book says this.

Comment: Doesn't say that any more...

Comment: Also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem. Thanks for your help

Comment: In DCT the functions _are_ integrable.